# How to get the cellular APN on iPad?

Tags: ipad, network, settings, ipados, cellular-data

I'm using iOS 5.0.1 on an iPad 1 and want to look at the APN settings.  This article from Apple http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2283 says that I should be able to see them through Settings > Cellular Data > APN Settings.  But when I go to Settings > Cellular Data, the only options are to turn data and roaming on and off, to view the account (which opens AT&T's account info) and an option to set a PIN on the SIM.

What is the APN information for an AT&T 3G ipad and/or how can I see it on my device?

Answer (score 1):

I can see my APN settings in:

Settings -> Mobile Data -> APN Settings

Perhaps your carrier locks this down?

Comment: What carrier do you have?

Comment: I am on an MVNO attached to O2, a UK carrier.

Answer (score 1):

If your carrier provides these settings on the SIM, then you won't be able to see or edit them as it's auto configured.

Answer (score 0):

If your carrier supports editing APN settings you can set settings using the instructions found in this site: [http://apn.gishan.net/platform_11_ipad__(default)_.php](http://apn.gishan.net/platform_11_ipad__%28default%29_.php)

Choose your network there and get the settings.